# At runtime, how can I determine programmatically how much memory is used by dynamically-linked libraries?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dll

I want to find out how much memory my application is using. I also want to know what part of my program is using the most memory. For example, I have a process that uses 100MB of memory, there is a .dll in that process that is using 90MB of memory. I would like to know "what" .dll takes that 90MB.

I want to take this value and use it in my program; I want to make a server where you can view the memory usage of separate parts.

This application is going to run on Windows.

Comment: What did Process Explorer tell you?

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question, I want to use those values in my application.

Comment: So, you want to find out _programmatically_. That's an incredibly important detail that you chose to leave out of your question.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

The question is utterly operating system dependent.

(I assume that DLL translates to dynamically loaded libraries and ELF shared objects in the Linux world)

For a Linux application, your application can sequentially read the `/proc/self/maps` textual pseudo-file.

If you know that your application process id is 1234, you can also read the `/proc/1234/maps` file, e.g. by typing in a terminal

```
 cat /proc/1234/maps
```

There are also `/proc/self/smaps` and `/proc/1234/smaps` which are slightly more detailed.

Comment: Os added, this program is going to run on windows.

Comment: When did Linux start supporting DLLs?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Earlier than Windows. But they are called shared objects.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: They are an equivalent technology that _also_ model the concept of shared objects. They are **not** DLLs, though. This is obviously a Windows question.

Comment: Edit: did't see your replay. Deleted this post.