# How to check how much memory used by a dynamic linked library in runtime?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, malloc

A lot third party dynamic linked libraries `liba.so libc.so libc.so` are used by our program on centos 7. Each library will alloc and destory memory in runtime. How to check how much memory used by a specific library?

Bellowing are two related questions, but can't solve this problem.

[I want to determine how much memory is used by dynamically-linked libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226918/i-want-to-determine-how-much-memory-is-used-by-dynamically-linked-libraries) Only give windows suggestions.

[At runtime, how can I determine programmatically how much memory is used by dynamically-linked libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194084/at-runtime-how-can-i-determine-programmatically-how-much-memory-is-used-by-dyna)
`/proc/pid/maps` only show mapped memory address range other than used size, and pathname `[heap]` do not show.

Comment: There's nothing in the posix malloc/free API to support this. You'll need to check the malloc library you're using, particularly its debugging features.  If you don't find what you need (which is likely), the next thing is bolt-on analyzers like [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

Comment: @Gene So you means recompile the library to be checked with a custom malloc function? Won't it also affect other libraries?

Comment: Each library has it's own debugging strategy (if it has one at all).  In the best case, debug features can be turned on in a debugger by resetting a static variable. Or you replace the normal dynamically linked lib with a different one. The library can profile by call site using the return value on the stack when malloc and free are called. These can be mapped back to lines of code with debugging symbol info.